# how to change a static final variable to thread local Multithreading?

Tags: java

I have a question about the race condition when multiple threads use the same variable.

For example:

```
private static final ContentHandler ORG_OMG_xmi = new RootXMLContentHandlerImpl(
    "org.omg.xmi", new String[] { "xmi" }, "xmi",
    "http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1", null);
```

How can I change ContentHandler  to thread local so I can use it with multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: The point of `static final` is to declare a variable that is accessible outside this class and that is immutable. It's not possible to update it's value. I don't know what do you wanna do with this variable but I think you need to explicit what you wanna do.

Comment: yes i access this variable outside the class with multiple threads at the same time so i must change it to thread local

Comment: You only have to make it thead local, if it is not thread safe.There is for example nothing wrong with a `public static final String` shared between multiple threads.

Comment: i know the problem is  private static final ThreadLocal<ContentHandler> ORG_OMG_xmi = new ThreadLocal<RootXMLContentHandlerImpl>(
   "org.omg.xmi", new String[] { "xmi" }, "xmi",
   "http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1", null); doesnt work

Comment: Just use `ThreadLocal`

Comment: @GhaithBriki why does that example not work?

Comment: Just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369526/4323935)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: There is no need to make every static field accessed by multiple threads thread local as long as the content of the field is known to be thread-safe. Good examples here are the typical immutable classes like `String`, `Integer`, ...

That said, you can wrap your `ContentHandler` in a `ThreadLocal` like this with Java8 and above:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<ContentHandler> ORG_OMG_xmi = ThreadLocal.withInitial(
    () -> new RootXMLContentHandlerImpl("org.omg.xmi", new String[] { "xmi" }, 
            "xmi", "http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1", null));
```

pre Java8 you can achieve the same with this:

```
private static ThreadLocal<ContentHandler> ORG_OMG_xmi =
    new ThreadLocal<ContentHandler>() {
        @Override public ContentHandler initialValue() {
            return new RootXMLContentHandlerImpl("org.omg.xmi", new String[] { "xmi" }, 
                "xmi", "http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1", null));
        }
    };
```

With `ThreadLocal` every thread will get it's own instance of `RootXMLContentHandlerImpl` which can be accessed by calling `get()` on the `ThreadLocal`:

```
ContentHandler myVeryThreadLocalContentHandler = ORG_OMG_xmi.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ContentHandler` to be thread local then you can declare and initialise it in `run` method (or a method that is invoked by `run`), e.g.:

```
public void run() {
    final ContentHandler ORG_OMG_xmi = new RootXMLContentHandlerImpl("org.omg.xmi", new String[] { "xmi" }, "xmi", "http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1", null);
}
```

This way, it won't be shared between threads.